# Minimal extension field of $\mathbb{F}_2$ such that

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, primitive-roots

> Find the minimal extension field of $\mathbb{F}_2$ such that this extension contains an element of order $21$?

---

Attempt: I know that such an extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$ is like $\mathbb{F}_{2^s}$ and $2|s$. Such a field has a primitive element, say $\alpha$ that generated the whole field. We know by theory that such a primitive element is such that $\alpha^i =1 <=> 2^s-1|i$

So, $\alpha^{21}=1 <=> 2^s-  1 |21$

So I need to find the minimum $s$ such that $2^s - 1$ divides $21$. $s=3$ is the good candidate ($s=1$ corresponds to $\mathbb{F}_2$ which is the base field).

Therefore, such an extension is $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}=\mathbb{F}_4$

**Is it correct?**

Comment: The multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_{2^s}$ is cyclic of order $2^s-1$, so you want $21\mid 2^s-1$. Divisibility the other way is silly, because $2^1-1=1$ divides anything.

Comment: Put another way, an element of order 21, should have order precisely 21, not just have 21st power 1.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry but I can't really understand why I want $21 | 2^s-1$. I just studied this theorem about primitive elements

Comment: @AlexJBest yes, 21 should be the minimum power such that $a^{21}=1$... but how can I use this?

Comment: Lagrange's theorem from elementary group theory: the order of an element divides the order of the group. Here the group has order $2^s-1$ so if you have an element of order $21$ then you must have  $21\mid 2^s-1$. This is a necessary condition. The primitive element theorem implies that it is also sufficient.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, really so I found that *necessarily* $s=6$. I'm trying to understand why the "primitive element theorem" gives sufficiency: it states that given a finite field of $q$ elements, there exists an element $\alpha$ that generates the field and $\alpha^i=1 <=> q-1|i$.

Comment: If $\ell$ is a factor of $q-1$, then $\alpha^{(q-1)/\ell}$ has order exactly $\ell$. Do you see why? If not, then review cyclic groups a bit, and it will become clear.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{F}_q$ has multiplicative group of order $q-1$. So, if I raise to $\ell$, then I have $\alpha^{(q-1)}$ which by assumption is $1$. 


So, if I have such an $s$  I know that $\alpha^i$ is exactly $1$, and hence I have sufficienc, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's incorrect. You need an element $a$ such that $a^{21}=1$, but $a^k\ne1$ when $0<k<21$.

Since the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, you need to find the least exponent $m$ such that $21\mid(2^m-1)$, which is the reverse of what you're doing.

The group must have order divisible by $21$, and this suffices because the group is cyclic (actually abelian would suffice).

You therefore need $3\mid(2^m-1)$ and $7\mid(2^m-1)$. The former condition yields $m$ even, the latter that $3\mid m$.

Comment: It's almost everything clear, but I don't understand how you derived $3| (2^m -1)$ and $7 | (2^m-1)$. DId you just factorize it in order to simplify computations, right?

Comment: @lukk That's standard: if $a,b$ are coprime, then $ab$ divides $c$ if and only if both $a$ and $b$ divide $c$. And yes, this simplifies the computation.